# how to send form data to your email in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am making a form using react.js and want to send form field data to email. i try this (action="mailto:example@gmail.com") but nothing happen.

i tried action mailto but nothing happens.
i want to see all fields data on my mail

Comment: are you aware that you need a own mailserver (or access to one) to do so?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to append all the form data attributes manually and open the email app like this

```
window.open("mailto:example@gmail.com?subject=Example Subject&body=all attributes here")
```

You can use back ticks instead of double quotes to easily add attributes like

```
`name: ${data.name}`
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way to use emailjs:

1. first sign-up
2. then add-service (keep the service id)
3. create email templates(keep the template id)
4. go to the account and keep the public key
5. go to your code:
6. create a component for email form, here is an example:

```html
import { useRef } from "react";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

const MailForm = () => {
  const form = useRef();
  const sendData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "service_id",
        "template_id",
        form.current,
        "public key "
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  };

  return (
    <form ref={form} onSubmit={(e) => sendData(e)}>
      FirstName:
      <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
      Email:
      <input type="text" name="Email" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
export default MailForm;
```

7. inside sendDate function in emailjs insert your service id, template id , and public key

Note: more appropriate to send the form first to your backend server and then send an email from the server